# How do you select data from an Excel table using certain parameters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope I made this question clear.

I have certain dummy data, which I want to make a selection on. 
For example:
The dummy data consists out of 25000 records. If I want to use: only about 5000 records which contains of 40% male and 60% female, between the age range of 20 to 60 where most people range around the age of 45 (certain distribution), how would I go about this problem.

> - 5000 records out of 25000
> - 40% male , 60% female
> - age distribution 45 years

example of distribution, where I would use some kind of slider to move the peak more to the right or left. I would most likely will do this by hand. Where the standard distribution has a peak between the min and the max.

[image: Example]

The reason why I would like to be able to make an age distribution, is because this data will be used for demo-dashboards. As some company's are either 'younger' or 'older' then others it wouldn't be logic to have 60 year old people in a dashboards when you present it to a young adult designer company, for example. This is thinking in HR data. the distribution is to have an average age the is only 1 or 2 20 year olds working in a company but 30, 29 year olds. I hope that clarifies it.

I have a vision that I make a selection worksheet with input fields where I can specify the minimum age and maximum age. Have a slider to specify what percentage of female I want to have, and a graph where I can specify how the age distribution must be.

Is this possible to do within Excel in anyway. Or would I need a different program for this to work, if so, what would be recommended?
I basically want to create a "selection program" within excel.

If I formulated the question wrong, or the details aren't clear I would love to hear.

Thanks in advance.

Jasper

Comment: "and a graph where I can specify how the age distribution must be" - you can specify sampling criteria like gender ratio or age limits, but asking for a sample which will give you an exact distribution sounds really weird. What is your goal with it. How do you want to create the chart (draw by hand?), how do you think it'll be transferred to computer readable data?

Comment: The reason why I would like to be able to make an age distribution, is because this data will be used for demo-dashboards. As some company's are either 'younger' or 'older' then others it wouldn't be logic to have 60 year old people in a dashboards when you present it to a young adult designer company, for example. This is thinking in HR data. the distribution is to have an average age the is only 1 or 2 20 year olds working in a company but 30, 29 year olds. I hope that clarifies it. As how to make this work, I have no idea.

Comment: How do you want to create the chart (draw by hand?), how do you think it'll be transferred to computer readable data? Please don't answer in a comment, but edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I would draw it by hand yes, I am imagining it as it has a standard distribution where the peak is between the min and max value. When you want to deviate from that you can drag the peak more to the right to create a different distribution. Excel would need to extract different records from the table to make the new distribution possible. The distribution is an extra however, it is not a Must, it is more a Would.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by using VBA.
I set up 1 worksheet with 10.000 male and one with 10000 female, just for convenience.

[image]

To calculate the distribution of 73% male and 27% female I used the following formula:
[image]

To get a random value from the database I used the following method:
[image]
where '10000man'!B is Row B in the worksheet where 10000 males are saved.

By pressing the button "bereken" (calculate) the following VBA code copies the value from B9 into column I en does that for B5 amount of times.
[image]

This is the code for the button:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(8).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(9).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(10).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(11).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(12).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(13).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(14).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(15).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(16).ClearContents
Worksheets("invoer").Columns(17).ClearContents
Range("H1").Value = "Gender"
Range("I1").Value = "FirstName"
Range("J1").Value = "MiddleName"
Range("K1").Value = "LastName"
Range("L1").Value = "Birtday"
Range("M1").Value = "StreetAdress"
Range("N1").Value = "City"
Range("O1").Value = "State"
Range("P1").Value = "PostalCode"
Range("Q1").Value = "TelephoneNumber"

'man
Dim Gender As Integer
    For Gender = 2 To Range("B5")
        Cells(Gender, 8) = Range("A9")
    Next Gender
Dim Firstname As Integer
    For Firstname = 2 To Range("B5")
        Cells(Firstname, 9) = Range("B9")
    Next Firstname
Dim MiddleName As Integer
    For MiddleName = 2 To Range("B5")
        Cells(MiddleName, 10) = Range("C9")
    Next MiddleName
Dim LastName As Integer
    For LastName = 2 To Range("B5")
        Cells(LastName, 11) = Range("D9")
    Next LastName
Dim Birtday As Integer
    For Birthday = 2 To Range("B5")
        Cells(Birthday, 12) = Range("E9")
    Next Birthday

'vrouw
Dim GenderV As Integer
    For GenderV = Range("C5") To Range("C6")
        Cells(GenderV, 8) = Range("A10")
    Next GenderV
Dim FirstnameV As Integer
    For FirstnameV = Range("C5") To Range("C6")
        Cells(FirstnameV, 9) = Range("B10")
    Next FirstnameV
Dim MiddleNameV As Integer
    For MiddleNameV = Range("C5") To Range("C6")
        Cells(MiddleNameV, 10) = Range("C10")
    Next MiddleNameV
Dim LastNameV As Integer
    For LastNameV = Range("C5") To Range("C6")
        Cells(LastNameV, 11) = Range("D10")
    Next LastNameV
Dim BirtdayV As Integer
    For BirthdayV = Range("C5") To Range("C6")
        Cells(BirthdayV, 12) = Range("E10")
    Next BirthdayV

'algemeen
Dim StreetAdress As Integer
    For StreetAdress = 2 To Range("C6")
        Cells(StreetAdress, 13) = Range("B11")
    Next StreetAdress
Dim City As Integer
    For City = 2 To Range("C6")
        Cells(City, 14) = Range("C11")
    Next City
Dim State As Integer
    For State = 2 To Range("C6")
        Cells(State, 15) = Range("D11")
    Next State
Dim PostalCode As Integer
    For PostalCode = 2 To Range("C6")
        Cells(PostalCode, 16) = Range("E11")
    Next PostalCode
Dim Telefoon As Integer
    For Telefoon = 2 To Range("C6")
        Cells(Telefoon, 17) = Range("A11")
    Next Telefoon
End Sub
```

I have not yet tackled the age distribution problem at this moment it is just a random date between 1950 and 2000. I will post a new question just solely for that problem.

How to distribute random dates for X amount in a Poisson distribution where the mean is a specified number and given a max and min value.

Thanks